# Android designing to fit all screens

Tags: android, xml

I am updating my Android app and realized that I have created a layout for every possible screen size (layout-small, layout-large, etc...) It would be a huge pain to go through every XML file and manually make a small change. I am attempting to create a single XML file to support all screen sizes. After reviewing the Android documentation and other questions on stackoverflow, it seems `LinearLayout` is the best choice as you can provide a `weightSum` and `layout_weight` for each item in the layout. This is not working as expected (see below code and images). I am doing this correctly? Do I have to go back to creating a `RelativeLayout` for every possible screen size?

Comment: you've missed the code and images ...

Comment: "see below code and images" Where?

Answer (score 0):

From my little experience I would say relative layout is more flexible from linear layout.
Anyway regarding for support screen sizes, you can add dimens folder to add different sizes & margins for different screen sizes